# Singularities of $z\mapsto\frac{z}{\mathrm e^z-1}$ and the Bernoulli numbers of its expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, bernoulli-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula, singularity

> Characterize all singularities of $$z\mapsto\frac{z}{\mathrm e^z-1}.$$
>
> What is the radius of convergence of the taylor expansion of $$\frac{z}{\mathrm e^z-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n\frac{z^n}{n!}$$ and deduce whether the $B_n$ are bounded?

Obviously $z=2n\pi\mathrm i$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$ are singularities. First let's take a look at $z=2n\pi\mathrm i$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. From l'Hôpital we obtain

$$
\lim_{z\to 2n\pi\mathrm i}\frac{(z-2n\pi\mathrm i)z}{\mathrm e^z-1}
= \lim_{z\to 2n\pi\mathrm i}\frac{2z - 2n\pi\mathrm i}{\mathrm e^z}
= \lim_{z\to 2n\pi\mathrm i}\frac{2}{\mathrm e^z}
= 2
$$

which is finite hence for all $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ those $z$ are **simple poles**.

But what about $z=0$? Can this same argument be applied to this as well?

(*Edit. What about analytic continuation - is it possible for $z=0$?*)

---

Furthermore from Cauchy's differentiation formula it follows with $\gamma=\partial B_\rho(0)$ that $$B_n=\frac{n!}{2\pi\mathrm i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{z}{\mathrm e^z-1}\cdot\frac{\mathrm dz}{z^{n+1}}$$ with $\rho\in(0,2\pi)$ since the curve would otherwise enclose one or more singularities. Therefore I assume that the radius is at most $2\pi$ and therefore all $B_n$ bounded as well. Unfortunately I did not come up with a proper proof why this may be true.

Comment: yes, $f(z) = \frac{z}{e^z-1}$ is holomorphic on $|z| < 2 \pi$ and has a singularity at $z = 2 \pi$ so its Taylor series at $z=0$ has a radius of convergence $2 \pi$, because of the Cauchy integral formula : $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{1}{2 i\pi}\oint_{|z| = r} \frac{f(s)}{s - z} ds =\frac{1}{2 i\pi} \oint_{|z| = r}  \frac{f(s)}{s} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{s^k} ds = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{2 i\pi} \oint_{|z| = r}  \frac{f(s)}{s^{k+1}}  ds$ valid for any $|z| < r < 2 \pi$

Comment: @user1952009 Does this imply that $f$ can be analytically continued at $z=0$ as well?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic Yes, $0$ is a removable singularity for $f$.

Comment: @egreg What's the intuition for this assumption? Since user1952009's application of the integral formula isn't quite clear to me I haven't seen why $0$ is removable and how this can be achieved.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{e^z-1}{z}=1$; take the reciprocal. Note also that you're applying L'Hôpital once too many.

Comment: @egreg Is this approch of taking the reciprocal described in any theorem or does it directly follow from something else since I haven't seen this method thus far.

Comment: $g(z) = e^z-1$ has a zero of order $1$ at $z=0$, as $h(z) = z$, so $f(z) = \frac{h(z)}{g(z)}$ is holomorphic at $z=0$ (with $f(0) = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{h(z)}{g(z)}$). the proof is straightforward, using that $H(z) = \frac{h(z)}{z}$ and $G(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z}$ are holomorphic at $z=0$ and $G(0) \ne 0 \implies \frac{H(z)}{G(z)}$ is  holomorphic at $z=0$,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{e^z-1}{z}=1
$$
you also have
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z}{e^z-1}=1
$$
so the point $0$ is a removable singularity for $f$; call $\hat{f}$ the extended function. Since $2\pi i$ is the nearest singularity to $0$ for $\hat{f}$ and it is a pole, we know that the Taylor series at $0$ has radius of convergence $|2\pi i|=2\pi$.

The points $2n\pi i$ ($n\ne0$) are simple poles for $f$, but you're computing the residue wrongly:
$$
\lim_{z\to 2n\pi i}\frac{z(z-2n\pi i)}{e^z-1}=
\lim_{z\to 2n\pi i}\frac{2(z-n\pi i)}{e^z}=2n\pi i
$$
(you can't further apply l'Hôpital). Alternatively, use the substitution $z=w+2n\pi i$, so the limit is
$$
\lim_{z\to 2n\pi i}\frac{z(z-2n\pi i)}{e^z-1}=
\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{w}{e^w-1}(w+2n\pi i)
$$

Comment: I think his problem is proving that $\frac{1}{h(z)}$ is holomorphic at $z=0$ when $h(0) \ne 0$ : $\frac{1}{h(z)} = \frac{1/h(0)}{1 - (1-h(z)/h(0))} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-h(z)/h(0))^k$ which converges and is analytic around $z=0$

Comment: @user1952009 If $g(z)=1/f(z)$, with $f$ holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z_0$ and $f(z_0)\ne0$, then $g'(z)=-\dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)^2}$, so $g$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z_0$.

Comment: @egreg Do you have some input on the possible boundedness of the $B_n$ in the second part?